# Terraform can't add github repo to Sagemaker space settings

Tags: terraform, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm trying to add a git repository to an AWS Sagemaker space, but on `terraform apply` I get the following error:

```
│ Error: updating SageMaker Space: ValidationException: Unknown parameter CodeRepositories in JupyterServerAppSettings for SpaceSettings.
│   status code: 400, request id: 492c767a-ad2b-4cd3-b0e8-d3b402d43a00
│ 
│   with module.sagemaker_studio_notebooks.aws_sagemaker_space.this,
│   on ../modules/sagemaker-studio-notebooks/main.tf line 65, in resource "aws_sagemaker_space" "this":
│   65: resource "aws_sagemaker_space" "this" {
```

It's happening for both space creation and modification.

Here is the terraform code:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_code_repository" "this" {
  code_repository_name = "this-code-repo"

  git_config {
    repository_url = local.repo_url
    secret_arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.github_login_token.arn
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.github_login_token,
  ]
}

resource "aws_sagemaker_space" "this" {
  domain_id = aws_sagemaker_domain.this.id
  space_name = "my-space-name"

  space_settings {
    jupyter_server_app_settings {
      default_resource_spec {
        instance_type = "system"
      }

      code_repository {
        repository_url = local.repo_url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Terraform backend:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.21.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.6.0"
}
```

I can see the git repo associated with the Sagemaker service in the AWS console. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: The provider version is unspecified in the question, but normally these issues arise from referencing a version of the documentation inconsistent with the version of the provider.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard ah ok, I updated the provider version and upgraded terraform locally; posted the provider code. Still same error though :(

Comment: How odd. The error message suggests that the AWS API itself is rejecting the `CodeRepositories` parameter (i.e., not a problem with your code); [the CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sagemaker-space-jupyterserverappsettings.html) do **not** show that parameter, but [the regular CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-space.html) apparently does. If you can, perhaps try creating a space using the CLI and see if you get the same error

Comment: Ok yes I read too quickly and that is a 400 HTTP error on the request body parameter, and not the Terraform parameter. There are various different possible causes for this error, but all of them would eventually lead to a raised issue on the AWS provider tracker. You could probably shortcut immediately to that step as they would investigate faster.